# How to create another Front Page and switch between the two? (in dev process)

Tags: 7

I am working on creating an alternative front page for an existing site. I do not want to disturb the existing front page but I just want to create another page (which I will later point to as front page - once design is complete).

Question: How do I create a page where I can add Blocks and other items? (I did it from Views - but doing so from Views requires me to add fields).

I do not want to add fields from views - want to do it entirely with blocks (even in the main content area)

Answer (score 2):

You can use context http://drupal.org/project/context to achieve this.  You can filter on the path and then add blocks to that specific page.

But you will need a holder page.  Sometimes I create a holder content type and then modify the node template to not display anything or just the title.  Then I can attach any view/block or w/e to it.  So that piece of content is just a "holder".